# Using mobile coordinate system to evaluate integral over a surface

Tags: differential-geometry

In my differential geometry class, my teacher suggested the following problem:

> Let $S$ be a connected regular surface such that, every normal line on the surface intersects on one single point. Prove that $S$ is a subset of a sphere.

My idea was the following:

First, we can start by assuming that the point of intersection is the origin (If this is not the case, we can simply apply a translation, and then undo it later). Let $p,q\in S$ with $||p||=k$. We want to prove that $||q||=k$. Because $S$ is connected, there is a smooth curve $\alpha:[0,1]\to S$ such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha(1)=q$ (I know that $\alpha$ might actually be piecewise smooth, but for now, I'm focusing on the case where $\alpha$ is smooth)

Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $\alpha(t_0)$ and $\phi$ a parametrization, then the normal line to $S$ in $\alpha(t)$ is given by $$\alpha(t_0) + \text{span}(\phi_u\times \phi_v)|_{\phi^{-1}\circ\alpha(t_0)}$$

---

The first thing I tried, but failed to prove, is that $\alpha(t_0)\in\text{span}(\phi_u\times \phi_v)|_{\phi^{-1}\circ\alpha(t_0)}$, meaning that $\text{span}(\phi_u\times \phi_v)|_{\phi^{-1}\circ\alpha(t_0)}=\text{span}(\alpha(t_0))$. However, intuitively this seams correct and makes sence.

---

With this, we have a mobile coordinate system for each point along $\alpha(t)$: $(\phi_u,\phi_v,\alpha(t)/||\alpha(t)||)$, where the partial derivatives are evaluated at $\phi^{-1}\circ\alpha(t)$ for each $t$, and in this coordinate system, the norm of $\alpha(t)$ equals the third coordinate.

I introduced this coordinate system, because given $p$ and $\alpha$, we can integrate $\alpha$ to get $q$:$$q=p+\int_0^1\alpha'(t)dt$$
where the integral is component-wise. Because, for all $t\in[0,1]$, $\alpha'(t)\in T_{\alpha(t)}S$, we know that the coordinates of $\alpha'(t)$ in the mobile coordinate system $(\phi_u,\phi_v,\alpha(t)/||\alpha(t)||)$ will be $(a(t),b(t),0)$, for some functions $a,b$.

The reason why I did all this work is the following:
The integral $$\int_0^1\alpha'(t)dt$$
Is basically summing all infinitesimally small $\alpha'(t)$ as we traverse $\alpha$, and on that mobile coordinate system, on the third component, we are integrating over $0$, as the third coordinate of $\alpha'(t)$ is always zero, meaning that on each infinitesimally small step in the direction $\alpha'(0)$, we won't get any closer of further from the origin. So if we can somehow make a change of coordinates on the integral, we might be able to evaluate it to something like $(\alpha,\beta,0)$ with $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R$, and when we sum this with the coordinates of $p$ in the mobile coordinate system, we get the following coordinates for $q:$ $(\alpha,\beta,k)$, thus proving that $||q||=k$.

---

My problem now is that I can't formalize this notion and because this relies so much on intuition, I don't even know if this is correct, or possible.
I already saw how my teacher solved this exercise using a different approach, but I can't let his idea go until I know whether this is possible or not.

Comment: Write down directly what it means to say that the normal line through $x$ passes through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's a really easy way to prove this locally, but let's entertain your idea. 
 As for the claim that $\alpha(t_0)$ is in the span of the normal vector, indeed suppose it wasn't. Then, the line connecting $\alpha(t_0)$ to the origin would differ from the normal. $\alpha'(t_0)$ would be perpendicular to the first line, but not to the normal, which is a contradiction. 
 As for your integral, notice that it is equivalent to $$p-q=\alpha(1)-\alpha(0)$$ This gives you no information about the defining caracteristic of a sphere, the constant distance from the origin to all its points. Think about it visiually: all you're saying is that a line connects $p$ and $q$, which crosses the sphere; yeah, the tangent vector may be tangent to the surface but the resulting integration is not. So I don't think this is the way to go. 
 There's a really easy way to do this noting that if $\nu$ is in the span of $p$, for some parametrization $p$, then $d\nu=-dp$. Then, integrating you get $-\nu=p-k,\, k\in \mathbb{R}^3$. Taking the norm on both sides you get $||p-k||=1$ and hence $S$ is a subset of  sphere.

Comment: Your really easy way oversimplified considerably. How did you get $d\nu = -dp$?

Comment: @TedShifrin   Because $\nu(u,v)=cp(u,v)$ (as they are in each others spans), their differentials are proportional to each other. Choosing that constant to be $-1$ results in no loss of generality, as it is equivalent to setting the radius to 1.

Comment: Still way too glib. $c$ is a function, not a constant. If your equation holds with $c$ constant, then you're done without going any further (why?).

Comment: @TedShifrin you're right it's not that straightforward I was getting ahead of myself. If I recall correctly the constancy of $c$ can be argued by regularity, when I check that I'll edit the post